# Add milliseconds to formatDuration in date-fns

Tags: javascript, react-native, date-fns

I want to convert a number of milliseconds to a human readable format using `date-fns` and React Native.

I've managed to do the conversion: `interval > duration > human readable format` and is works fine all the way to **seconds** but **milliseconds** are omitted.

Current code:

```
 const niceFormatDuration = (intervalInMs) => {
    const milliseconds = Number.parseInt(intervalInMs % 1000, 10);
    const duration = intervalToDuration({ start: 0, end: intervalInMs });
    return formatDuration(duration);
 };
```

The above code is working fine, but missing milliseconds. I've added the milliseconds to the duration object with:

```
duration["milliseconds"] = milliseconds;
```

But `formatDuration` still only returns down to seconds.

Also tried to add a new `milliseconds` format to `formatDuration`, but a error is thrown.

```
{
      format: [
        "years",
        "months",
        "weeks",
        "days",
        "hours",
        "minutes",
        "seconds",
        "milliseconds", // Not working with this line
      ],
    }
```

Obviously I could manually add the milliseconds in the end of the string, but that looks ugly:

```
return `${formatDuration(duration)} ${milliseconds} ms`;
```

Comment: maybe change `intervalInMs % 1000, 10` to `intervalInMs % 1, 10`? Never used that library, but why not convert date with vanilla js?

Answer (score 0):

From date-fns docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/Duration

Duration object doesn't store milliseconds, so it's not possible.

Adding additional property to the object won't change the implementation of functions working with duration. Function simply doesn't expect nor looks for this property.

You need to append milliseconds by yourself.